# Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $|A| = n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N.$ Prove that the convex hull of $A$ is the smallest convex set containing $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I am aware that there are similar threads to this, but since I am very new to this sort of math, I couldn't make sense of them too much.

Here's a proof(?):

Suppose $B$ is a convex set and $C$ is a convex hull of $A$ such that $A \subseteq B \subseteq C \subseteq \mathbb R^n.$ If $A = \{v_1, v_2, v_3,\ldots,v_n\}$, then $C = \{a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 \ldots a_nv_n | 0 \le a_i \le 1, \sum_1^n a_i = 1\}.$ Since $A \subseteq B$ and $B$ is a convex set, $B$ must be a(?) convex hull of $A$. We know $\sum_1^n a_iv_i \in C$ and since $B$ is a convex hull of $A$, $\sum_1^n a_iv_i \in B$ must be true. Then $C \subseteq B$ which implies $B = C.$

Can we argue like that? Thanks.

Comment: You can say: $A\subset B$, so $v_j \in B$ for $1 \le j \le n$. As $B$ is convex, $\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j v_j \in B$ for any $0 \le \alpha_j \le 1$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j =1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your definition of the convex hull of $A$, is the definition you gave for $C$.  If this is true, then the convex hull is unique and so saying "a" convex hull makes no sense.  A better way to argue is to assume $B\supseteq A$ is a convex set and show $C\subseteq B$.

Comment: Let $x, y \in A.$ Then  $ax + by \in C$ with $0 \le a \le b \le 1$ and $a + b = 1.$ Suppose $x, y \in A$, then $x, y \in B$ and thus $ax + by \in B$ with $0 \le a \le b \le 1$ and $a + b = 1.$ Does this work?

Comment: You can't assume $a\le b$.  This will not account for all members of $C$.  Say $0\le a,b\le 1$.

Comment: If I do as you say, can I claim that the given statement is proved?

Comment: Your argument only proves the case when $A=\{x,y\}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I just have to generalize. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, I believe you can do this by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

No, your argument is circular. The confusion seems to stem from talking about "a" convex hull. But **the** convex hull is unique.

In a successful proof, you'll use the assumption that $B$ is a convex set. What does this assumption mean, by definition? How does it relate to $C$?

Comment: If $x, y \in B$, then $tx + (1 - t)y \in B$ for $0 \ge t \ge 1.$ Since $tx + (1 - t)y \in B$, then $tx + (1 - t)y \in C$?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not really sure what you're saying there. What assumptions are you starting from, and what relationship between $B$ and $C$ are you proving?

Comment: I assume $A$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb R^n.$ I am trying to show that $C$ is a subset of $B$ where $C$ is taken to be the convex hull of $A$ and B is a convex set.

Comment: Ah, well, in order to show that $C$ is a subset of $B$, you have to demonstrate that an arbitrary point in $C$ also belongs to $B$. (Not the other way around)